# Regex Split by period unless between Brackets or between Curly Brackets or between Double Quotes

Tags: regex

I am trying to write a regex pattern and use the split function to split on all period unless those periods are between open and closing Brackets OR Curly Brackets.  I thought I had it right since in an online regex tester it correctly highlighted the periods I want to split on by when I run the split it splits on more than just periods and creates a long list.  I think I am doing something obviously but can't seem to figure it out. Please see below for what I have so far. Thanks!

What I have so far:

Regex so far:
.(?=([^]]*([)[^[]*(]))*[^]]*$)(?=([^}]*({)[^[{]*(}))*[^}]*$)(?=([^"]*(")[^"]*("))*[^"]*$)

EX String (Should only split on first occurrence of period):
PARENTCOLENUM.[{COLID.NAME_COLUMN_OID}] {.} [.] "."

Test Site Link (Looks right until you click the Split List tab and then it shows its splitting it up by more than the period.

http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5c.%28%3f%3d%28%5b%5e%5c%5d%5d*%28%5c%5b%29%5b%5e%5c%5b%5d*%28%5c%5d%29%29*%5b%5e%5c%5d%5d*%24%29%28%3f%3d%28%5b%5e%5c%7d%5d*%28%5c%7b%29%5b%5e%5c%5b%5c%7b%5d*%28%5c%7d%29%29*%5b%5e%5c%7d%5d*%24%29%28%3f%3d%28%5b%5e%5c%22%5d*%28%5c%22%29%5b%5e%5c%22%5d*%28%5c%22%29%29*%5b%5e%5c%22%5d*%24%29&i=PARENTCOLENUM.%5b%7bCOLID.NAME_COLUMN_OID%7d%5d+%7b.%7d+%5b.%5d+%22.%22

Comment: You're missing a `)` at the end of the first regex.

Comment: If you surround the sample regex or sample text with back tics it will highlight the text  (in a fixed font) making  it easier to read.

Comment: Generally this is not a good way to do it. When you depend on even pairs of trailing delimiters you have to go to the end of string every time. In your case, its doing it 3 times per match. This is the regex you're using `\.(?=([^\]]*(\[)[^\[]*(\]))*[^\]]*$)(?=([^\}]*(\{)[^\[\{]*(\}))*[^\}]*$)(?=([^\"]*(\")[^\"]*(\"))*[^\"]*$)`

Comment: It looks like you're using Dot-Net. This engine does balance text via the stack. If you care about nesting, you should consider using that.

Comment: Usually it's first come first serve for delimiters. What you're doing is jumping over and into delimiters to match other delimiters. This allows overlap of content. A quoted string could hide brackets `"asfdffg]]"` etc... See if you can define those possible outcomes a bit better.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I figured it out just by testing some regex options. Use Regex Options: RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture

My final regex pattern for anyone that may want to reference in the future is:
.(?=([^(]|}|"")]*([|{|"")[^([|{|"")]*(]|}|""))*[^(]|}|"")]*$)